# Capybara testing editablegrid features not working

Tags: capybara, editablegrid

Using editablegrid.net. Really like the layout and functionality.
The only problem is feature testing.
Nothing seems to work in capybara - page snap doesn't show the page content for the actual grid, matchers dont see content rendered in js.

I have to use an older phantom (v1.9.2) as support for capybara doesn't seem to be there on mac os x yet.

Anyone had any luck feature testing?

Things tried

- page refresh: page.driver.browser.navigate.refresh
- made sure turned on using turbolinks events for load
- tried selenium and poltergeist

**Setup details**

*versions*

```
        rails 4.1.0
        capybara (2.9.1)
        rspec (3.5.0)
        phantomjs 192

        selenium-webdriver (2.53.4)

        poltergeist (1.5.1)
          capybara (~> 2.1)
          cliver (~> 0.3.1)
          multi_json (~> 1.0)
          websocket-driver (>= 0.2.0)

    $ phantomjs -v
    1.9.2
```

**UPDATE**
updated versions

```
   $ phantomjs -v
    2.1.1
    $ gem list | grep polter
    poltergeist (1.10.0)
    $ selenium-webdriver (2.53.4)
```

however when I do a simple test

```
      visit 'address_books/'+user.address_book.id.to_s
      page.save_screenshot("file1.png", :full => true)
      sleep 4.seconds # just in case the delayed redraw takes time
      page.save_screenshot("file2.png", :full => true)
      expect(page).to have_content(/Person A.*2 8888 9999.*home/)
```

where this page includes an `editablegrid` that works fine in development (See example screen shot (http://imgbox.com/rqwx1vHe) ) doesn't render in the save screen shots ( http://imgbox.com/t1CG6hQa )

other notes

- I tried selenium also, same problem : it is clear that the grid does not display.
- I have used turbo links load for the event to trigger page load.

**grid code**

```
                  var editableGrid = null;
        $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
                        editableGrid = new EditableGrid("AddressBookGridJSON"); 
                        editableGrid.tableLoaded = function() { this.renderGrid("tablecontent", "testgrid"); };
                        editableGrid.loadJSON('/address_books.json');
                        // $.getJSON('/address_books.json', function(json) {
                        //     editableGrid.load({"metadata": json.metadata,              "data": json.data});
                        //     console.log(editableGrid);
                        // });
                    });
```

**UPDATE 2**

`index.json.jbuilder`

```
        json.set! :metadata do
        json.array! @address_book.generate_view_table_meta_data
        end

        json.set! :data do
            json.array! @contacts do |contact|
              json.id contact.id
                  json.set! :values do
                      json.name contact.name
                      json.phone_number contact.get_presentation_number
                      json.phone_type contact.get_humanize_phone_type
                      json.action contact.get_url_to_view_delete
                  end
            end
        end
```

**UPDATE 3**

*Data base* cleaner code loaded

require 'database_cleaner'
        RSpec.configure do |config|
          config.before(:each) do
            DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
          end

```
      config.before(:each) do
        #DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
        # if we use transaction the data is NOT saved during the actual rspec scenario. we must have commit
        # during rspec so external compare processs can access data
        # TODO make this conditional based on the compare plans process only

        # tests will not have :nontransactional defined except compareplans testing
        if self.class.metadata[:nontransactional]
          DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
        else
          DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
        end
      end

      config.before(:each, :js => true) do
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
      end

      config.before(:each) do
        DatabaseCleaner.start
      end

      config.append_after(:each) do
        DatabaseCleaner.clean
      end
    end
```

Comment: Poltergeist 1.5.1 is over 2 years old and phantomjs 1.9.2 is so old it's basically useless with any modern JS frameworks/libraries.  Upgrade to the latest poltergeist (1.10.0 currently) and install phantomjs 2.1.1+ - on OSX you can install the latest phantomjs with homebrew - if you still have issues after that then give us an example of the test you're doing that's failing, and the errors you get.

Comment: thanks Tom. I knew it was old, probably not that old. I have now upgraded (phantoms 2.1.1 and poltergeist 1.10.0 but no change. NOTE I could have sworn capybara had problems with latest phantom that seems to work now. UPDATE original answer with test

Comment: Configure your poltergeist driver with js_errors: true and make sure you don't have JS errors - https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#customization

Comment: How are you creating the data to be shown in the grid?  Make sure you're not using transaction mode testing.

Comment: ok so these are the settings: `feature 'Address Book', :devise => true, :js => true,  :js_errors => true, nontransactional: true do` so non transactional , no errors raised (also checked when running in dev console). Its weird that in selenium the page isn't displaying either...

Comment: nontransactional is not a setting you turn on/off like that without other code to handle it - it means setting up your database/app so they aren't using transactions to add data to the database but never committing it, which means it won't be visible to another thread (like the thread the app runs in if you add the data in the test) - see https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#transactions-and-database-setup and https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example

Comment: I'd also like to see the code that you have to handle :js_errors => true metadata because you can't change that on the driver without registering a new driver, and you really don't want to be doing that for every test since you'll rapidly run out of memory

Comment: thanks for ongoing interest Tom, apologies this is a part time thing for me so dipping in and out. I pasted in database cleaner code. note i've been using this a while as we have a compiled process that accesses the rails DB that relies on this cleaner code for tests.

Comment: Re: js_errors - this is new to me - i thought that js_errors just flagged whether errors were ignored or not. i've gone back to register the driver with options set to true `options = {:js_errors => true} Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|; Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options); end` No difference - no additional errors. googling i can't find anything other than 'setting param to true or false' - what am i missing?